# Location selector picker input widget

Tags: android, android-widget, geolocation

What I want to do:

- display a text box as an input field, which will accept a city name (any city throughout the world)
- as the user starts typing, I'll auto-(complete/suggest) city names.
- when the user selects a city name from the dropdown, the name appears in the text box as well, and the background gets highlighted to a very light blue.

Is there any existing widget that does this? If not, what would be a good way to auto-(complete/suggest) city names?

Edit: I know AutoCompleteTextView does autocompletes. The problem is more about dealing with an exhaustive datasource of cities (hopefully available as an API online somewhere), and connecting the widget with this list of datasource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already pointed out yourself, a widget as described could be fairly easily built using standard components in the Android SDK, with the main one being an `AutoCompleteTextView`. In terms of "where to get the city data from", you basically have two options:

1. Bundle the data with the app.
2. Use a webservice.

Both obviously have their pros and cons. Bundling the data will blow up your APK size, a lot, whereas webservices are usually subject to a courtesy limit. Whichever option is the 'best', will depend on several factors, including the size of your app's userbase.

Some concrete resources for bundling the data:

- [MaxMind's Free World Cities Database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities) (33MB)
- [GeoNames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) (**233MB!**)

And webservices:

- [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) (cc-by licence, 30k requests/day, 2k requests/hr).
- [Google Places API - Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) (1k requests/day, or 100k requests/day if you verify your identity with Google, or try your luck and [request a higher courtesy quota](https://developers.google.com/places/uplift))

Note that these lists are by no means exhaustive - I'm sure there are plenty of other options. They should offer you a decent starting point though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the AutoCompleteTextView class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: Is there an API that I can plug this widget into so that it auto-completes itself? If not, is there anywhere I can get the exhaustive list of cities in the world?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is something similar to Typeahead address picker.

https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker

It can both recommend autocomplete while you type, and use a map to select/show the address. Looks good :)